# Month over month % without having month in the viz

Tags: tableau-api

```
Columns:
Rows: Product, SUM(Number of Records)
Text: Percent Difference using SUM(Number Of Records)
Filter: Created Date set to Previous Month and added to context.
```

My problem is that the % in difference uses the number of records from the previous row in the table. This would give me a percentage difference for each product in the table. Rather, I need something like the below;

If we have data as such;

```
product - month - number of records
Java    - nov   - 25
Java    - dec   - 50
```

Then I would want a table in my viz which would look similar to the below.

```
+------------+---------+
|   Product  |  MoM%   |
+------------+---------+
| Java       | 100%    |
+------------+---------+
```

I would rather not have the month in the viz because I would get 30 products for every month which is too many rows. The above is ideal, the product with the MoM% of the previous month over two months ago. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have tackled something this is to create Calculated Fields for current month and last month as well as a calculated field for the growth.

**First Calculated Field 'Current_Month'**

```
IF [MONTH] = 'dec' then [number of record] END
```

or (depending on your data setup)

```
IF [MONTH] = 'current' then [number of record] END
```

**Next Calculated Field for 'Last_Month'**

```
IF [MONTH] = 'nov' then [number of record] END
```

or (depending on your data setup)

```
IF [MONTH] = 'last' then [number of record] END
```

**Then calculated field for the difference**

```
([Current_Month] / [Last_Month) - 1
```